# PhoneGap Event volumeupbutton and volumedownbutton is not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using PhoneGap Api 1.4.1 and also I tried with 1.5.0, The PhoneGap Event volumeupbutton and  volumedownbutton is not working, neither it works on android device nor it works on emulator.when the volume button up or down is  pressed it must display the alert see the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
   <html>
    <head>
    <title>PhoneGap Volume Down Button Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Call onDeviceReady when PhoneGap is loaded.
    //
    // At this point, the document has loaded but phonegap.js has not.
    // When PhoneGap is loaded and talking with the native device,
    // it will call the event `deviceready`.
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Register the event listener
        document.addEventListener("volumedownbutton", onVolumeDownKeyDown, false);
        document.addEventListener("volumeupbutton", onVolumeUpKeyDown, false);
    }

    // Handle the volume down button
    //
    function onVolumeDownKeyDown() {
      alert("Down");
    }
    function onVolumeUpKeyDown() {
      alert("Up");
    }

      </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I also Tried this in iphone it is not working on it as well:(

Comment: Wrong Question Not Supported in Iphone And Android :P

Comment: What is a wrong question? You are free to delete your question or answer it yourself if you feel your question is unnecessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do the following, to get the volume button running with android:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    //If volumedown key
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
        this.loadUrl("javascript:cordova.fireDocumentEvent('volumedownbutton');");
        return true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        this.loadUrl("javascript:cordova.fireDocumentEvent('volumeupbutton');");
        return true;
    } else {
        //return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
    }
    //return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    LOG.d(TAG, "KeyUp has been triggered on the view" + keyCode);
    // If back key
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        this.loadUrl("javascript:cordova.fireDocumentEvent('backbutton');");
        return true;
    }
    // Legacy
    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        this.loadUrl("javascript:cordova.fireDocumentEvent('menubutton');");
        return true;
    }
    // If search key
    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {
        this.loadUrl("javascript:cordova.fireDocumentEvent('searchbutton');");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I copied this code from a cordova bug report. This code is valid for cordova 2.0. I thin you'll have to change "cordova.fireDocumentEvent" to "phonegap.fireDocument" or "PhoneGap.fireDocumentEvent"

**update:**
Just wrote a small blog-post about the bug, that was solved by the code above. The link to the Cordova-Issue-Tracker can be found in that post: http://christian-kuetbach.de/blog/post/13

**update 2:**
The Issue seems to be fixed within cordova 1.9:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-871

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you provide it as phone gap plugin

Comment: i have cordova-1.8.1.js i need for this one also

Comment: I think it would be easier, if you overwrite Your native entry-point (the class, that inherits from DroidGap) and just path it there. I think I'll file a bug report in the cordova-project.

Comment: need to be frank still i dont know about java code i am a learner pls help me

Comment: Solution 1: Update to phonegap 1.9
Solution 2: (If you don't use phonegap build) Open your only *.java File and add to code above to that file. (Search for the last } and add it before).

Comment: hi i have updated to the latest phone gap plugin which is 2.0 now what i need to do can you explain me please

Comment: This is not my question i can give you the bounty in 22 hrs

Comment: Sorry, my fault, thought it was your question.