# Android Volume Key Event Capture

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am currently developing an app for `android`..

how i can capture the `volume` key event when user press in android phone

i am using **phone gap**...

Comment: Which version of phonegap are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the below code to get the key event

Use this code in your existing java class

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    //If volume down key
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
        this.loadUrl("javascript:cordova.fireDocumentEvent('volumedownbutton');");
        return true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        this.loadUrl("javascript:cordova.fireDocumentEvent('volumeupbutton');");
        return true;
    } else {
        //return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
    }
    //return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    return true;
}
```

and using this below in your html page

```
document.addEventListener("volumeupbutton", onVolumeUpKeyDown, false);  

document.addEventListener("volumedownbutton", volumedownbutton, false);

function    onVolumeUpKeyDown()
{
    alert("Working Up")     
}

function    volumedownbutton()
{
    alert("Working Down")       
}
```

I Got This Answer From Here [**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770901/phonegap-event-volumeupbutton-and-volumedownbutton-is-not-working**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770901/phonegap-event-volumeupbutton-and-volumedownbutton-is-not-working)

Comment: Hey, I am trying to add that inside of my class but I get: "The method on KeyDown must override or implement a supertype method". What am I missing?

Comment: My plugin class is named as this: public class AudioAPI extends CordovaPlugin{....}  Don't I need to extend the Activity to use that event?

Comment: @leo2_uru you have to add the code in your main class file [mainclass.java]

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work either. Do you mean with mainclass the one with the "public class AudioAPI extends CordovaPlugin {}" implementation? I tried to add that inside of that class but I am still getting the same error. The class that I should extend from should be the Activity, right?

Comment: i have added that code in my main activity file. i think that you need to extend main acitivy

Comment: Which is your main activity file? I don't have that one, I guess... Is that the one you reference in the config.xml?

Comment: @leo2_uru pls refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770901/phonegap-event-volumeupbutton-and-volumedownbutton-is-not-working

Comment: Thank you! I added that to the "main" Java file and it's working now: the one with the "public class AudioDemo extends CordovaActivity " declaration. I wasn't aware of that file because I am creating a custom Cordova plugin to be used later on a Telerik/appbuilder app. Do you know how should I add that override into a custom plugin? Is that possible? Maybe the problem is my lack of knowledge in Java because I know that I have to create a class that extends from the CordovaActivity but I don't know if I am doing that ok on the custom plugin...

Comment: I got that using this: webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() { 
          public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
           
               if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
                //LOG.d("AudioAPI", "Volume Key touched");
                      return true;
                  }

                  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){
                   //LOG.d("AudioAPI", "Volume Key touched");
                      return true;
                  }
                  return false;
          } 
     });

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in Phonegap API Docs, This following code works only in Blackberry:

```
document.addEventListener("volumeupbutton", yourCallbackFunction, false);
document.addEventListener("volumedownbutton", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

But there's nothing harm in checking it out. It might work with the latest Phonegap SDK

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can add events listener in the PhoneGap for volume key buttons as described in the PhoneGap Documentation like [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#volumedownbutton)

Thanks

Comment: Did you see this in the link you gave me `Supported Platforms 

BlackBerry WebWorks (OS 5.0 and higher)` i have already tried it its not working

Comment: @AppMobiGurmeet  vaahost is correct it will not work do you have any other soulition

Comment: now it works with the lastest version  check the documentation 6.0.0 https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.volumedownbutton.html