# phonegap : Detect volume change

Tags: ios, cordova, mgwt

I have an phonegap application, and I need to trigger an event when a button is pressed on the device (not a button on the screen).

Is there a way to detect, say, volume change (in iPhone and maybe other devices too) ?

I use [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/), [mgwt](http://code.google.com/p/mgwt/) and [gwt-phonegap](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Volume Key Event Capture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890170/android-volume-key-event-capture)

Comment: @Jennis this is about the implementation using `gwt-phonegap`, so it's not an exact duplicate

Comment: that is why possible duplicate.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a simple event when such a button is pressed from gwt-phonegap.

Your code would look like this:

```
 phoneGap.getEvent().getVolumneUpButtonPressedHandler().addVolumneUpButtonPressedHandler(new VolumeUpButtonPressedHandler() {

  @Override
  public void onVolumeUpButtonPressed(VolumeUpButtonPressedEvent event) {
    // volume up button pressed

  }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.. i tried your code but the event does not seem to fire. Is there a plugin I need to add for that ?

Comment: (tested on iPhone 4, iOS 5.0.1 and cordova 1.8.1)

Comment: which version of gwt-phonegap are you using?

Comment: `gwt-phonegap 1.8.1` .. I just tried the simplest example from http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_events_events.md.html#volumedownbutton and it doesn't work either.. maybe there's something wrong with my jailbroken device..

Comment: Tested the same code with an Android device and it still doesnt work. Has this been fixed in later versions of gwt-phonegap?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890170/android-volume-key-event-capture) for Android. There appears to be a [PhoneGap plugin for iOS](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/VolumeSlider) which lets you control the volume. This could be modified to fire an event on volume change.