# phonegap - iPhone Volume Key Event Capture

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova

I'm try to make an app for iPhone and Android with Phonegap, and I want to be able to use the volume buttons as user inputs.

I found this solution for android: [PhoneGap Event volumeupbutton and volumedownbutton is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770901/phonegap-event-volumeupbutton-and-volumedownbutton-is-not-working)

But I'm not sure how to do this for iPhone. Any ideas?

Thanks.